# Relationship between classical electromagnetic wave frequency and quantum wave function + de broglie frequency

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, waves, quantum-electrodynamics, wavefunction, frequency

As it is.

As I study through classical mechanics and quantum mechanics, I began to wonder whether there is a relationship between classical electromagnetic wave frequency and quantum wave function and de broglie frequency).

I think this is somehow related to quantum electrodynamics...but anyway.

Comment: You should clarify your question. Do you mean  the de Broglie wavelength/frequency associated with particles? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie_wavelength . Or are you thinking of photons? Photons are associated with the frequency of the wave by E=h*nu but it is not a wavefunction ( i.e. probability distribution) relation .

Comment: @annav I edited my question. Can you have some look over it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waves appear in nature and are described by [wave equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation)s,

> second-order linear partial differential equation for the description of waves – as they occur in physics

All such equations have time dependent solutions and what they have in common is the oscillating behaviour in time that allows to assign a wavelength and describe the waves observed.

Now in quantum mechanics the description of the behavior of nature is dependent on  differential equations of this type. The first studied is the [Schrodinger equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation)   and the link provides a good historical description of how it became evident that in the microcosm the behavior of particles was following a wave equation.

What is important to keep in mind is that **in quantum mechanics the waves are probability waves**, i.e. the probability if you do an experiment, like the [double slit experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment), to find a particle in space at the time you look is governed by a wave solution. This is in contrast to other  waves in physics which are variations in time on a medium, or in classical electromagnetism on changing fields.

So the relationship is the mathematical formulation of the differential equations describing nature in the two frameworks, not a one to one correspondence.

As I mentioned in my comment in electromagnetism, the frequency of the electromagnetic field described by classical electrodynamics appears in the energy of the photon ( the particle form of electromagnetism) in the identity *E=h.nu*. The interference pattern seen in the double slit experiment will display the frequency of light *nu*. If you continue your studies in physics you will be able to understand  how the microcosm described by quantum mechanics leads to the macrocosm we call "classical physics" smoothly.